# Using Prawn with Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, forms, web, sinatra

> How can I use Prawn to generate PDF of form data in Sinatra?

My form is at the index action of the site but Prawn doesn't recognize the variables passed in. I've found this code in the documentation at http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html.

```
get '/download' do 

  content = "Hello World"

  Prawn::Document.generate "example.pdf" do |pdf|
    pdf.font "Times-Roman"
    pdf.draw_text content, :at => [200,720], :size => 32
  end
end
```

Now this is great, but when I try to pass in my variables from the parameters like this:

```
post '/resume' do 
  @name = params.fetch 'name' 
  ...
end
```

And then if I add that into the /download route like this:

```
get '/download' do 

  Prawn::Document.generate "example.pdf" do |pdf|
    pdf.font "Times-Roman"
    pdf.draw_text @name, :at => [200,720], :size => 32
  end
end
```

It it will draw nothing. Also, weirdly, it generates a pdf file but doesn't redirect to it and I have to manually load it.

Really stuck on this one - advice?

Comment: Are you sure that `name` isn't blank? Try to log it and make sure.

Comment: No, it's not blank. I even stripped out the params.fetch 'name' part and just set @name equal to "name" and it still won't print out on the pdf.  The problem appears to be that the Prawn cannot interact with variables outside of the route it's in.  I even tried making name a global variable and it still cannot access them.

Comment: Weird. Try doing `d = Prawn::Document.new do |pdf|....` Then call `d.render_file('example.pdf')`

Comment: I tried that but still can't get it. Honestly, it seems Prawn cannot handle variables outside of its route. I think there are plenty of Rails implementations. Maybe I should rebuild the app in Rails.  I tried one last effort by including a "before do" block to pass in a variable but it still doesn't render on the pdf. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

[Every request creates a new instance of your Sinatra app to serve it](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope). Therefore, instance variables won't be the same across 2 different requests. You either need to persist the data using one of the many ways to do this (cookies, local storage, database, cache etc) or you need to put the Prawn logic in the POST route.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that makes complete sense. I just started with Sinatra and web dev in general and sometimes get stuck on things. I'm looking to implement sessions in the app now.

Comment: No problem - we've all been there! :)